# Android YouTubePlayer - get event on certain time of playing

Tags: android, android-youtube-api

I need make some action after video have played 50% of its length.

So I did not see some listener with something like "onCertainMills()", I see onVideoEnded() but I need get event when current time of played video will more then length/2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end of the ends I have made class to make action on certain second of playing video.
Here is the code to make some action after half time of the video playing: (+ 1 sec) Hope it will help to someone.

```
import android.os.Handler;
import android.util.Log;

import com.clipclash.android.entities.Clip;
import com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayer;

public class YoutubeCounter {

    Clip clip;
    long counter;
    long startCut;
    long endCut;
    long durationGoal;
    private YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer;
    boolean goal = false;
    Handler h;


    Runnable checkGoal = new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            getProgress();
            if (counter >= durationGoal) {
                // GOAL !!!
                //TODO MAKE SOME ACTION
                goal = true;
                stopSchedule();
            } else {
                startSchedule();
            }
        }
    };

    public YoutubeCounter(Clip clip) {
        this.clip = clip;
        h = new Handler();
    }


    public void setYouTubePlayer(YouTubePlayer youTubePlayer) {
        this.youTubePlayer = youTubePlayer;
    }

    public void play() {
        if (!goal) {
            if (durationGoal == 0) {
                durationGoal = this.youTubePlayer.getDurationMillis() / 2;
            }
            startCut = youTubePlayer.getCurrentTimeMillis();
            startSchedule();
        }
    }

    public void stop() {
        if (!goal) {
            getProgress();
            stopSchedule();
        }
    }

    private void startSchedule() {
        long newSchedule = durationGoal - counter;
        newSchedule = newSchedule + 1000; // just a little bit more - not requires
        h.postDelayed(checkGoal, newSchedule);
    }

    public void stopSchedule() {
        h.removeCallbacks(checkGoal);
    }

    private void getProgress() {
        try {
            endCut = youTubePlayer.getCurrentTimeMillis();
            long cut = endCut - startCut;
            if (cut < 0) {
                cut = 0;
            }
            counter += cut;
        } catch (Exception e) {
        }
    }

    public long getCounter() {
        return counter;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the YoutubePlayer's property getCurrentTimeMillis() to constantly obtain the time and getDurationMillis() to get the video's total duration. Thus, you can set the desired task when the youtubePlayer.getCurrentTimeMillis() >= youtubePlayer.getDurationMillis() with an asynctask.
The code will look like this:

```
    player.setPlaylistEventListener(playlistEventListener);
    player.setPlayerStateChangeListener(playerStateChangeListener);
    player.setPlaybackEventListener(playbackEventListener);

    AsyncTask a = new AsyncTask(); //listener for time
    a.execute(player, 2000,this); //player, time, and activity

    if (!wasRestored) {
      playVideoAtSelection();
    }

    setControlsEnabled(true);
```